# How to change a list item rendering according to its content?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-listview, android-xml

I am using a `ListFragment` with a `CursorAdapter` to display a list of items. The XML layout is pretty simple: it only consists of the title, a description and the number of comments.

[image: Simple list item layout]

Instead, I would like to show the **number of comments on the right side**. If it is possible I would like to add an image or a colored box as a **background frame**. Further, I would like to **change the image/color according to the number of comments**.

[image: List item layout]

This is the layout file I am currently using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="@dimen/padding_small" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comments_count"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the CursorAdapter that I use ...

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.comments_count = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.comments_count);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TITLE));
        holder.title.setText(title);
        int comments_count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COMMENTS_COUNT));
        holder.comments_count.setText(comments_count + "");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView comments_count;
    }

}
```

Here is a **color function** I prepared according to Thiago Moreira Rocha's example implementation ...

```
if (comments_count == 0) {
    holder.comments_count.getParent().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
else if (comments_count != 0) {
    float saturation = (comments_count * 15) / 100.f;
    // The value gets pinned if out of range.
    int color = Color.HSVToColor(new float[] {110f , saturation, 1f});
    holder.comments_count.getParent().setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

How would you implement the layout and the context sensitive behavior?

---

**Note:**

I created a second question to discuss the option to [make the comment box clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431592/android-how-to-attach-multiple-touch-actions-to-a-single-list-item). Please refer to the new post if you want to add information to this topic.

Comment: Changing the look is a simple matter or changing the xml. For the background changes, try overriding the getView() function of the adapter which allows you to control individual lines. There are quite a few examples out there on how to use it. Hope this helps...

Comment: That's what I meant in my example! Use you color function inside your `bindView` method to update the parent's background view!!! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your adapter's `getView` method(in your case, `bindView`) get the parent of the view that will be bound and update it's background color with `View.setBackGroundColor`!

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
   //usual stuff
   //...
   Color newColor = colorFunction(comments_count);//calculate your new color
   View v = (View)view.getParent();
   v.setBackgroundColor(newColor);
}
```

In this example, I've created a list using `ArrayAdapter`, with a **NAME** followed by a random **NUMBER**. I wrapped this number inside a `LinearLayout` and according to it's value I change his parent layout.

Check my example below.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ColorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mockData));
}

String[] mockData = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6",
        "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 11", "Item 12" };

public class ColorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ColorAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        label.setText(mockData[position]);

        TextView desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description);
        desc.setText("Description: "+ mockData[position]);

        TextView value = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comments_count);

        //Here is the object you need to change the colors.
        LinearLayout background = (LinearLayout) value.getParent();

        Random random_number = new Random();
        int comments_count = random_number.nextInt(256);

        value.setText(comments_count+"");

        //Calculates a random color
        int newBackgroundColor = colorFunction(comments_count); 

        //Set the new background color on the comments_count parent
        background.setBackgroundColor(newBackgroundColor);

        return row;
    }

    private int colorFunction(int commentsNumber) {
        if (commentsNumber == 0) {
            return Color.WHITE;
        }
        else if(commentsNumber < 0) {
            return new Random().nextInt(256);
        }
        else {
            int color;
            Random rnd = new Random(); 
            color = Color.argb(commentsNumber, rnd.nextInt(commentsNumber), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(commentsNumber));

            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**row.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comments_count"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp"
            android:right="15dp" android:bottom="15dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" /> 
</shape>
```

The resulting list(portrait and landscape) are below.

[image: List in portrait]

[image: List in landscape]

Comment: Your example look pretty promising, however, I use a `CursorAdapter` not an `ArrayAdapter`. I added the relevant code to my question.

Comment: Sorry, but also the layout is part of the problem.

Comment: Could you please try to build the layout I sketched in my question? I am having problems positioning the box on the right side. Also, its position shifts when the text left of the comment box changes in length (similar to what I can see from your picture).

Comment: That's easy to fix. Set the weight of the child views with a fixed value. I'll add a picture with your layout

Comment: That looks nice. I noticed, however, that the **width** of the box is **not fixed**. That means it changes its size when the text is longer then others or I put the device into **landscape mode**.

Comment: Well, you can set in the description 'TextView' the properties `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:lines="1"` I added a new screenshot and a minor change in the `row.xml`

Comment: I want the comment box on the right to have a **fixed width** and **height**. As you proofed by the landscape screenshot, the dimensions change.

Comment: If you want a fixed value you can try the same approach suggested here [link](http://goo.gl/FJdfT)