# How to attach multiple touch actions to a single list item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, onclick, android-listfragment

I am using the following list layout for *items* that have associated *comments*. The number of *comments* are indicated by the box on the right side.

[image: Item list layout]

Currently, I am using the `onListItemClick` handler to launch another *details* view.

```
public class CustomListFragment extends ListFragment
                                implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private QueryParameters mQueryParameters;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setEmptyText("No data to display");

        mActivity = getActivity();
        if (mActivity == null)  {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Activity is null");
            return;
        }
        // Prepare query.
        mQueryParameters = QueryHelper.getQueryParameters(mActivity);
        if (mQueryParameters == null || !mQueryParameters.isPreparedForLoader()) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "One or more query parameters are null.");
            return;
        }
        mAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(mActivity, null, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle extras) {
        return new CursorLoader(mActivity,
                mQueryParameters.uri,
                mQueryParameters.fromColumnsLoader,
                mQueryParameters.selection,
                mQueryParameters.selectionArgs,
                mQueryParameters.sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ItemDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ITEM_URI", mItemUri);
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I would like to implement that the user can touch the box element on the right. This action should then start the associated `CommentsActivity`. When the user touches the left side, however, it should still launch the `ItemDetailsActivity`.
In both cases, I need to pass the `itemUri` with the intent so that either the *details* view or the *comments* list for the particular *item* can be loaded.
The `ListFragment` uses a `CursorAdapter` to bind the `TextView`s to the properties of an *item*.

**Question:**

- How can I attach a second touch action to a single list item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hadn't posted any code relating to the adapter itself, but I found your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12350711/1267661) and you are most of the way there.

### The Quick and Dirty Answer

In `bindView()`, let's modify your `comments_count` TextView to save the index of the current row in the tag (for your `itemUri`) and add a simple OnClickListener:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    if (holder == null) {
        ...
        holder.comments_count.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get the position from the ViewHolder
                long id = (Long) v.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Comment Click: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    holder.comments_count.setTag(cursor.getLong(0));
}
```

When the user clicks on the row it will still call `onListItemClick()`, except if they click on the comments box. The comments box fires the OnClickListener above where you can direct the user to your `CommentsActivity`. You didn't mention where you fetch the different values for `itemUri` but I assumed you need the row's id to get it.

---

### Superior Answer

In your previous question, I noticed that you are making some repetitive calls and that Thiago Moreira Rocha's layout was extremely complex to be used repeatedly (for every ListView row.) So I propose a different approach. I've divided my answer into parts relating to the adapter, row layout, and colors for `comments_count`:

**The Adapter**
I'll post the code in full and then explain at the bottom:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int[] mFrom;

    private OnClickListener commentClick = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the position saved in bindView()
            long id = (Long) v.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Comment Click: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private void applyColorFilter(Drawable drawable, int count) {
        drawable.clearColorFilter();
        if (count > 0) {
            float saturation = (count * 15) / 100f;
            // The value gets pinned if out of range.
            int color = Color.HSVToColor(new float[] {110f, saturation, 1f});
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, Mode.SRC);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(mFrom[0]));
        holder.description.setText(cursor.getString(mFrom[1]));

        // Get comments_count and set it as text
        int count = cursor.getInt(mFrom[2]);
        holder.comments_count.setText(count + "");
        holder.comments_count.setTag(cursor.getLong(0));

        // Adjust the color by saturation
        applyColorFilter(holder.comments_color, count);

        // Alternate method, that I explain in the answer
        //   Note: set the solid color in color.xml to #2aff00 
        //holder.comments_color.setAlpha(count * 45);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.comments_count = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.comments_count);
        holder.comments_count.setOnClickListener(commentClick);
        holder.comments_color = ((LayerDrawable) holder.comments_count.getBackground()).findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.color);

        view.setTag(holder);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if(mFrom == null && newCursor != null) {
            mFrom = new int[] {newCursor.getColumnIndex(TITLE), newCursor.getColumnIndex(DESCRIPTION), newCursor.getColumnIndex(COMMENTS_COUNT)};
        }
        return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        TextView comments_count;
        Drawable comments_color;
    }
}
```

I made a few changes:

- `mFrom` holds the indices of the columns that you are using. You only need to get the column index *once*, it won't change unless you change the Cursor
- `commentsClick` is *one* generic OnClickListener that I use for *every* row and I set it while creating a `ViewHolder`
- I brought your method for changing the HSV color into the adapter and called it `applyColorFilter()`
- I moved creating the `ViewHolder` into `newView()` rather than checking for a `null` one in `bindView()`

---

**The Row Layout**
You probably noticed that I change the comments' color a little differently, that is because I use a simpler row layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comments_count"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comments_count"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comments_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/comments_layers"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(While [Thiago Moreira Rocha's layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352314/1267661) works, the nested ViewGroups seem like overkill. Anytime you have a ViewGroup with only one child, their is usually an alternative.)

I use a LayerDrawable to replace the two LinearLayouts, that I will explain in in steps.  **First,** the border (`border.xml`), very similar to the previous one:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

(Notice the padding is the width of the stroke.)

**Second,** the adjustable background color (`color.xml`):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

**Last,** I created a LayerDrawable to combine the two images (`comments_layers.xml`):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border" />
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:drawable="@drawable/color" />
</layer-list>
```

---

**(Optional)**
You adjust the saturation of your HSV value in `applyColorFilter()`, but it seems that this is the equivalent to adjusting the alpha of a green background. If this is true, the changing the alpha value is a much simpler task. Find my comments in `bindView()`:

1. Comment out `applyColorFilter(holder.comments_color, count);`
2. Uncomment `holder.comments_color.setAlpha(count * 45);`
3. Open my `color.xml` file and change the `color` attribute of the `solid` element from `#ffffff` to `#2aff00`

---

In all truth I had never used LayerDrawables like this before, there may be a faster way, but I think this is pretty slick.

Comment: I don't think I can use the `onClick` attribute in the XML file. I need to pass at least the item URI to one of the other activities. Please mind my edit.

Comment: Ok, the best solution is to extend your adapter. Have you seen the video? If so start by overriding `newView()` from `SimpleCursorAdapter` and initialize the `ViewHolder`, in `getView()` update the current the `itemUri` or `position`, and finally in both `OnClickListeners` you can start the new Activity with the current URI. (I'm happy to help you code any part of this, if you post what you have tried.)

Comment: I appreciate your answer and comments. I am currently writing my thesis which I hand in in five days! I need every minute to finish it and cannot spent too much time on trial and error. If I have time left I will definitely watch the video and follow your suggestions. No offense please.

Comment: I found the time to review your answer (thesis submitted). It looks very promissing however I am stucked in the middle. As you can see from the fragment class which I use, I initialize the adapter with a **null cursor**. This causes a `NullPointerException` in the constructor of the fragment (but later, too). Could you help me out once again with your advice, please?

Comment: Congratulations on submitting your thesis! I hadn't planned on a CursorLoader when I first wrote this, but I modified my code to accept a `null` Cursor. Let me know how this works for you. (I remember I had fun writing this answer, if you didn't notice from how _long_ it is.)

Comment: Thank you (more then once)! It works fine now. Awesome implementation. I would not have been able to come up with it! Still I have questions: Why did you subtract minus one from the *comment count*?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18197/discussion-between-sam-and-jjd)